Overload the double operator in Dart
In Dart, I can override the toString method to change the string content returned by an object when it is used as a string.
I need to change the object's behavior when it is used as a double.
I would like to achieve the same result from this C++ code in Dart:
class Value {
private:
  double value;
  Color color;

public:
  Value(double value, Color color) : value(value), color(color) {}
  operator double() const {
    return value;
  }
};

Meaning that I would be able to use an object from the class Value like this:
Value value = const Value(value: 13.0, color: Colors.blue);

double a = value + 3; // a = 16.0
double b = value - 3; // b = 10.0
double c = value; // c = 13.0


There is no operator double  in dart. You could create a method toDouble instead.

can you share a little dart code and explain in simple words what you want to acheive?

@MunsifAli sure. Here is my Dart code.

To achieve a similar result, you could define the addition operator + and the subtraction - operator of the Value class:
class Value {
  final double value;
  final Color color;

  const Value({required this.value, required this.color});

  @override
  String toString() => "The value is $value.";

  double toDouble() => value;

  double operator +(num other) {
    return value + other;
  }

  double operator -(num other) {
    return value - other;
  }
}

Your main.dart would then become:
void main() {
  final value = Value(value: 13.0, color: Colors.blue);
  double a = value + 3; // a = 16.0
  double b = value - 3; // b = 10.0
  double c = value.toDouble(); // c = 13.0
  double d = value.value; // d = 13.0
}


